# Create directory structure in Amazon Elastic Block Storage(EBS) and save files from Java Servlets?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am very new to this and trying to do this the first time. I have learned that `Amazon Elastic Block Storage(EBS)` can be used in a similar way as a hard Disk when mounted on Amazon EC2. Now I wish to create a directory structure in EBS and save files from Java Servlet in EBS?

I have also learned that the code used by the servlet in development machine can be used to create a directory structure access files in EBS also

```
@MultipartConfig( location          = "d:\\tmp", 
                  fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024, 
                  maxFileSize       = 1024 * 1024 * 5,
                  maxRequestSize    = 1024 * 1024 * 5 * 5  )
```

I have Amazon Linux installed on my Amazon EC2, any pointers will be great help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an Amazon EC2 micro instance, then you already have an EBS root device attached to it and you can create directories and save files into it, just like you would do in a non-EC2 linux box. The default root device usually has a size of 8 GB, but you could add additional EBS devices if you need more space.